# Why error is coming when using listings in polyglossia package?

Tags: listings, fontspec, polyglossia

The complete file is [here](https://www.mediafire.com/file/p9dtw9nzphdstpe/ElegantBook-3.11.zip/file).
**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[11pt,fancy,authoryear,twoside]{elegantbook}
    
%--------------------------------------------------
%Bengali Font in Document
%--------------------------------------------------
\tracinglostchars=2
% For a bilingual document
\RequirePackage{fontspec}
\RequirePackage{polyglossia}

\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX, Scale=MatchUppercase}
% Times New Roman used for English
%\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
%\setmainfont{Times New Roman}[NFSSFamily=ntxtlf]
\setmainlanguage{bengali}
\setotherlanguage{english}

% Bengali
\newfontfamily\bengalifont{Kalpurush}[
  Script=Bengali,
  Language=Bengali,
  AutoFakeBold = 0.2,
  AutoFakeSlant = 0.15  ]


\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\chaptername~\thechapter \, #1\,}{}}
\titleformat{\chapter}[\style]{\bfseries}
     {\filcenter\LARGE\enspace\bfseries{\color{structurecolor}%
       \IfAppendix{\appendixname}{\chaptername~\thechapter}\enspace}}
     {1pt}{\bfseries\color{structurecolor}\LARGE\filcenter}[]



%End--------------------------------------------

\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter


\begin{lstlisting}
import numpy as np
 \end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

When I am using Listings, errors occurred:  ``

```
 ! Package polyglossia Error: The current roman font does not contain the Bengal
```

". Everything is fine except the package "`\usepackage{listings}`". How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

From experimenting with a dozen random fonts, Kalpurush font does not seem to have the necessary ligatures. Try Nikosh font instead for the main font.

Also, not all fonts survive the transition into the listing environment. Try Mukti font.

In listings, non-ASCII characters need to be escaped, as do commands etc that need to be Latex-ed.

Not all fonts have: (1) all characters, (2) all ligatures, and (3) Bengali and Latin combined; so the amount of work to do to get printable copy inside listing environment depends on what is required. Some choices and decisions may have to be made to save the amount of typing.

[image: bengali sampler]

Note: "Poly env {bengali}" is for testing the listings environment and refers to a `\begin{bengali}\fontoverride ... text\end{bengali}` code structure. Nikosh font, for example, is perfectly fine inside the plain environment, but not with a font override, so breaks inside listings.

The quote is from the solar system article on Wikipedia.

MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt,fancy,authoryear,twoside]{elegantbook}
    
%--------------------------------------------------
%Bengali Font in Document
%--------------------------------------------------
\tracinglostchars=2
% For a bilingual document
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{bengali}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX, Scale=MatchUppercase}
% Times New Roman used for English
%\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
%\setmainfont{Times New Roman}[NFSSFamily=ntxtlf]
%\setmainlanguage{bengali}
%\setotherlanguage{english}

%সৌরজগৎ
\setmonofont{Mukti}[Colour=blue,Scale=1.2]%Mitra Mono}%Akaash}%Jamrul}%Likhan}
\newfontface\fban{Vrinda}

\newcommand{\য}{\textcolor{red}{সৌরজগৎ} হল সূর্য ও প্রত্যক্ষ বা পরোক্ষভাবে[ক] সূর্য-প্রদক্ষিণকারী তথা পরস্পরের প্রতি অভিকর্ষজ টানে আবদ্ধ মহাজাগতিক বস্তুগুলিকে নিয়ে গড়ে একটি ব্যবস্থা। আকাশগঙ্গা ছায়াপথের কেন্দ্রস্থল থেকে ২৬,০০০ আলোকবর্ষ দূরে কালপুরুষ বাহুতে এই গ্রহ ব্যবস্থাটি অবস্থিত। }
\newcommand{\প্রতি}{abc প্রতি  xyz 123}

% Bengali
\newfontfamily\bengalifont{Nikosh}[
  Script=Bengali,
  Language=Bengali,
%  AutoFakeBold = 0.2,
  AutoFakeSlant = 0.15  ]
\newfontface\fbana{Vrinda}[Script=Bengali]
\newfontface\fbanb{Akaash}[Script=Bengali,Scale=1.5]
\newfontface\fbanc{Jamrul}[Script=Bengali,Scale=1.2]
\newfontface\fband{Noto Serif Bengali}[Script=Bengali]
\newfontface\fbane{Likhan}[Script=Bengali,Scale=1.2]
\newfontface\fbanf{Mitra Mono}[Script=Bengali,Scale=1.5]
\newfontface\fbang{Sagar}[Script=Bengali,Scale=1.5]
\newfontface\fbanh{Nikosh}[Script=Bengali]
\newfontface\fbani{Mukti}[Script=Bengali,Scale=1.5]
\newfontface\fbanj{Kalpurush}[Script=Bengali]
\newfontface\fbank{Lohit Bengali}[Script=Bengali,Scale=1.5]
\newfontface\fbanl{Ekushey Saraswatii}[Script=Bengali,Scale=1.5]


\newcommand\tbn{সৌরজগৎ  প্রতি abc }

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\chaptername~\thechapter \, #1\,}{}}
\titleformat{\chapter}[\style]{\bfseries}
     {\filcenter\LARGE\enspace\bfseries{\color{structurecolor}%
       \IfAppendix{\appendixname}{\chaptername~\thechapter}\enspace}}
     {1pt}{\bfseries\color{structurecolor}\LARGE\filcenter}[]

\newcommand\bb[1]{\begin{bengali}#1\end{bengali}}

%End--------------------------------------------

\usepackage{listings}


\begin{document}

\maketitle

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\chapter{সৌরজগৎ}
\য
%\begin{english}
\begin{lstlisting}[escapechar=\#]
import numpy as np

\newcommand{#\textbackslash#য}{#\textbackslash#textcolor{red}{# \fbani সৌরজগৎ#} #হল সূর্য ও# ...}
#\textbackslash য#
#\textbackslash##\fbani প্রতি# $\mapsto$ #\fbanl\প্রতি#
#\textbackslash##\begin{bengali} প্রতি \end{bengali}#
 \end{lstlisting}
%\end{english}


\begin{tabular}{ccr}
Standalone font & Poly env \{bengali\} & Font \\
\hline
\fbana\tbn & \bb{\fbana\tbn} & Vrinda\\
\fbanb\tbn & \bb{\fbanb\tbn} & Akaash\\
\fbanc\tbn & \bb{\fbanc\tbn} & Jamrul\\
\fband\tbn & \bb{\fband\tbn} & Noto Serif Bengali\\
\fbane\tbn & \bb{\fbane\tbn} & Likhan\\
\fbanf\tbn & \bb{\fbanf\tbn} & Mitra Mono\\
\fbang\tbn & \bb{\fbang\tbn} & Sagar\\
\fbanh\tbn & \bb{\fbanh\tbn} & Nikosh\\
\fbani\tbn & \bb{\fbani\tbn} & Mukti\\
\fbanj\tbn & \bb{\fbanj\tbn} & Kalpurush\\
\fbank\tbn & \bb{\fbank\tbn} & Lohit Bengali\\
\fbanl\tbn & \bb{\fbanl\tbn} & Ekushey Saraswatii\\
\hline
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the problem is that polyglossia wants to access use Bengali script in the program listing, even though you're not typing Bengali there. Since the font there is typewriter type, and the Computer Modern typewriter fonts don't support Bengali you get that answer.

Two possible solutions: Option one, find a typewriter font that supports Bengali (e.g., FreeMono). Option two (and this might be the better option), wrap your `listing` environment with `\begin{english}`…`\end{english}`.

Comment: @ DonHosek Unfortunately it is not working. Errors: '! Package polyglossia Error: The current roman font does not contain the Bengali script!(polyglossia) Please define \bengalifont with \newfontfamily.See the polyglossia package documentation for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help.... \begin{lstlisting}'

Comment: Option two works for me. With option one, there is right-ro-left output occurring.

Comment: `\setmonofont{Mukti}` removes the error. Mukti font has both Latin and Bengali. Both options from @donhosek are correct: either remove listings from the Bengali space (option 2), or add it to the Bengali space with a suitable (`\ttfamily`) Bengali font (Option 1). Mukti is proportional, not fixed-with. I don't have FreeMono (yet).